# backbone.js $el for subview not available at the time the parent view initializes it

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-views

I'm trying to render a subview within a view in Backbone. I'm following this example:

http://backbonetutorials.com/examples/modular-backbone/

which seems to work fine. This is my code for the parent view:

```
define([
  'jquery',
  'underscore',
  'backbone',
  'models/products/ProductsModel',
  'views/products/ProductsFiltersView',
  'text!templates/products/productsTemplate.html',
], function($, _, Backbone,ProductsModel,ProductsFiltersView,productsTemplate){

  var ProductsView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: $("#page"),

    initialize: function(){
      var self = this;
      self.model = new ProductsModel();
    },

    render: function(){
      var pageTitle = this.model.get('title');
      document.title = pageTitle;
      var pageData = {
        title: pageTitle
      }

      var compiledTemplate = _.template( productsTemplate ); //prerender template
      this.$el.html(compiledTemplate(pageData));

      this.renderFiltersView();

    },

    renderFiltersView: function(){
      var productsFiltersView = new ProductsFiltersView();
      productsFiltersView.render();
    }

  });

  return ProductsView;

});
```

And this my code for the subview:

```
define([
  'jquery',
  'underscore',
  'backbone',
  'text!templates/products/productsFiltersTemplate.html',
], function($, _, Backbone,productsFiltersTemplate){

  var ProductsFiltersView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: $(".filters.product"),

    events : {
          "click .filter-options-container" : "filterOptionContainerClick"
    },

    initialize: function(){
      var self = this;
    },

    render: function(){
      var compiledTemplate = _.template( productsFiltersTemplate ); //prerender template
      this.$el.html(compiledTemplate()); //this.$el.length = 0;
      //$(.filters.product').html(compiledTemplate()) //this works


      this.inlineSVG($('.filter-option')); //need to convert img tags to inline svg so we can manipulate their fill color dynamically
    }
  })

  return ProductsFiltersView;

});
```

No errors are being thrown, and if I change the this.$el.html in the subview to an action jquery selector, the view is rendered, but I want to fix the overall problem, which is that this view is being instantiated before the parent view's DOM contents are ready. Anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

--EDIT--

Here is my parent template

```
<div class="page-container products cf">
    <div class="products-and-filters">
        <div class="products-container">

        </div>
        <div class="filters product">

        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="wishlist products">

    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Where does `.filters.product` come from? Is that generated by the parent's template perhaps?

Comment: filters.product is generated by the parent's template, yes

Comment: Then it won't be in the DOM when you expect it to be. There's always `new SubView({ el: this.$('.filters.product') })`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
this.setElement(".filters.product")
```

in initialize method of subview

Comment: Edited your answer and it works now. Welcome to stack overflow!